# A sci-fi book or TV show about a tribesman discovering he or she actually lives in a huge spaceship

Tags: story-identification

The story starts with a tribesman going on a exploratory voyage around the land, meeting other progressively more and more distant tribes, learning about the world. Gradually he or she discovers that the "world" is actually a giant spaceship flying through space.

The story climaxes by the hero ascending to the commanding deck and learning who actually pilots the ship and to what purpose.

Comment: Possibly Robert Heinlein's [Orphans of the Sky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphans_of_the_Sky).  Were there mutated people on the upper decks?.

Comment: This could match a number of stories, depending on how accurate the description and memories of it are.  It could be _The Starlost_, for example, or maybe even a not well remembered version of _Ringworld_ (if the reader remembered Teela's "friend" who was on his question).  If the asker isn't sure if it's TV or a book, then details could be mis-remembered.

Comment: Generational starship story maybe ?  Would be helpful to have a timeframe.  When did you you read or view this ?

Comment: Harry Harrison's Captive Universe, perhaps? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_Universe

Comment: Or Brian Aldiss' Non-Stop? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Stop_%28novel%29

Comment: · The reason I don't know if is's a book of TV show is that I only remember reading some review of that story. · I faintly remember that there was supposed to be quite a lot of decks on that ship, like 18 or so, and the heroes were gradually progressing through those. · I haven't realized that such plot is actually quite common general scheme in the generation ship stories and there is quite a number of those. Oh well…

Comment: Without more details, this is not a story identification question: you're only describing one plot thread, and it's a relatively common one. A story identification question needs some unique details, enough that when someone tells you the answer you can reply “yes, that's the one”.

Comment: Among the countless published stories, my favorite version is http://writings.mike-combs.com/alfasfer.htm

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I think it is probably Orphans of the SKy or Non-Stop, maybe The Starlost. When I can check those out the books in a library and the show somewhere else, I'd know. I am sure it is NOT Ringworld, or Captive Universe nor Morbus Gravis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try to go through some Generation Ship stories list and try to see for yourself if any match your memories. [This list on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/generation-ship) could be a good start.

The first book on that list, [*Non-Stop*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/384579.Non_Stop) (1958) by Brian W. Aldiss fits your description quite well. There is a tribe, two members of which go on an exploratory journey, and discover the world is a starship... just as you said.

> Curiosity was discouraged in the Greene tribe. Its members lived out their lives in cramped Quarters, hacking away at the encroaching ponics. As to where they were - that was forgotten.
>
> Roy Complain decides to find out. With the renegade priest Marapper, he moves into unmapped territory, where they make a series of discoveries which turn their universe upside-down...

Comment: I checked out the suggested books and at first sight it is Non-Stop. So I accepted this answer.

Comment: Just finished the book. Loved the parts about the crazy  religion. Can recommend. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A TV show that fits the description, 'The Starlost', and a follow-up novelization
by Harlan Ellison, **Phoenix Without Ashes** comes to mind.   There were
subplots for each episode, and I'm unsure that there was a final wrap-up,
my recollection is that it just... ended with its first season.